# Ruby Retrieve the Last Upserted Mongo Document

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb

I am referencing the following url http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/ which to me is of no help in my quesiton. I wanted to know if I used the following code

```
coll.update({ :count => 5 }, { :count => "foobar" }, { :upsert => true })
```

is is possible to get the upserted document without making another database call? Links to better documentation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `:count => "foobar"` are you sure there is no typo?

Comment: nope, its an example in the supplied link, unless double quotes are wrong in this context

Comment: http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/Mongo/Collection.html#update-instance_method - I don't think the `upserted` document can be obtained without making another call. Normally other drivers do return the original document matched by the selector, but ruby driver doesn't seem to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Ruby MongoDB Driver requires a separate database call to retrieve data. Although it can perform an upsert there is no way to get the upserted document with a single database call. So you have to do something like this

```
coll.find({ :count => "foobar" })
```